# Xamarin android different layouts for activationbar tabs

Tags: android, layout, tabs, xamarin

I'm using the following code to use tabs in my application

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        ActionBar.NavigationMode = ActionBarNavigationMode.Tabs;
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        ActionBar.Tab tab = ActionBar.NewTab();
        tab.SetText(Resources.GetString(Resource.String.ProfileTab));
        tab.SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.Icon);
        tab.TabSelected += (sender, args) =>
        {
            // Do something when tab is selected
        };
        ActionBar.AddTab(tab);
        //
        tab = ActionBar.NewTab();
        tab.SetText(Resources.GetString(Resource.String.Charges));
        tab.SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.Icon);
        tab.TabSelected += (sender, args) =>
        {
            // Do something when tab is selected
        };
        ActionBar.AddTab(tab);
        // Create your application here
    }
}
```

In this code both tabs use the "Main" layout. I want to use two different layout for each tab.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use ActionBar.Tab.SetCustomView()